# Broken Do/While Loop

Tags: c

```
char again;
do {
            counter = 0;
            while (counter < 3) {
               printf("Please enter a number: ");
               scanf("%d", &num);
               counter++;
               sum += num;
            }
            if (counter == 3) {
                printf("Would you like to continue? [Y]Yes [N]No:");
                scanf("%c", &again);
            } 
        }while (again == 'Y');
```

I can't seem to figure out why this won't work.  If i enter Y it breaks, if I enter N it breaks.  I need to loop until the user enters "N" to exit the program and no other letter.

Comment: It changes in the while loop...

Comment: BTW, shouldn't you write `} while (again != 'N')`?

Comment: why `if (counter == 3)`? It *must* be 3, and if it weren't and that conditional could fail then you would have undefined behavior if `again` wasn't initialized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `scanf` call to:

```
scanf(" %c", &again);
```

The trick is in the space before the `%c`: it instructs the `scanf` function to ignore any whitespace character before returning your N or Y. Otherwise you will be reading the return carriages from the previous `scanf` calls.

From [`man 3p scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) (the POSIX one):

> A directive composed of one or more white-space characters shall be executed by reading input until no more valid input can be read, or up  to  the
>          first byte which is not a white-space character, which remains unread.

That is a complex function. I recommend reading the man page with care: it can do much more than most people think.

Comment: @iccthedral: What is an instruction in C? AFAIK, `scanf` is a function.

Comment: @iccthedral: Ahh! They are called _directives_, not instructions. You can read about it in any _good_ reference of the _scanf_ function, such as the POSIX man pages (see the link in the updated answer).

Comment: @iccthedral: I don't want to seem pedantic but... it's not a matter of taste of one or other name. They are called this way in the language reference, so we should call it exactly that. Otherwise we are asking for confusion.

Comment: @rodrigo I completely understand you, and I wasn't referring to the taste when I said "better suited". It is; exactly because of what you said and I know that now - so again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `scanf("%c", &again)` reads the newline after the last number, which is why the loop always breaks.  It's also why people shun `scanf()` in favour of `fgets()` plus `sscanf()`; you tend to get better diagnostics and fewer nasty gotchas like this.

How could you have debugged this for yourself?

You could have printed the data that is read as it is read — add:

```
printf("Read: %d\n", again);
```

after the `scanf()`.  Also, you should be checking each `scanf()` call to ensure you are getting the data you expect:

```
if (scanf("%c", &again) != 1)
    ...oops — error handling...
```